# Android: onDataSetChanged() call in ListFragment doesen't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, notifydatasetchanged

I have a ListFragment in which I am listing all available Bluetooth devices. However, when I switch between fragments in my application and than switch back to the ListFragment, all the data in the adapter are still there, but the List isnt showing anything. Here's the code
:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> allDevices;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);  
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    if (allDevices != null) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : allDevices) {
            listAdapter.add(device.getName()+ "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);  
}
```

When I add items to the ArrayAdapter for the first time and call notifyDataSetChanged, it works perfectly fine. However, when I leave the ListFragment and than come back, It should show the same List as before, but it isn't showing anything. Not even when I add the data to the ArrayAdapter again as before. The ArrayList from which I'm adding the data to the ArrayAdapter in the onCreateView function is not empty.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Did you add Log statements and it's definitely re-adding items to the list adapter?  Also, is there a good reason for extending ListFragment other than setting an adapter inside of it (well, it looks like you've extended it)